# MPDF - table border and cell boders are not showing with css but HTML is working

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, mpdf

I am using laravel framework. here in my code HTML table view is ok.But when i am converting the same to pdf using mpdf, the table is displaying without any borders. i am using css in same html. no external style sheets are included
my code is here

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        td{
           border-top: 1px dotted black;
           border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
           border-left: 1px dotted black;
           border-right: 1px dotted black;
        }
        table {
            margin-left: 5px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        td {
            border: 1px solid black; 
            
        }

    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="pdf">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Role ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="font-size: 14px;">
            @foreach ($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->mobile }}</td>
                    <td style="width: 20%;">{{ $user->password }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->department_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->i }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my controller
<?php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mpdf\Mpdf;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
// use phpDocumentor\Reflection\PseudoTypes\False_;

class PdfController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('pdf',compact('users'));
    }
 
    public function generate()
    {
        require_once base_path('vendor/autoload.php');
        $defaultConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
        $fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];
        $defaultFontConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
        $fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];
        $custom_font_path = storage_path().'\fonts';
        // dd($custom_font_path);
        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
            'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
               $custom_font_path,
            ]),
            'fontdata' => $fontData + [
                'gayathri' => [
                    'R' => 'Gayathri-Regular.ttf',
                    'useOTL' => 0xFF, 
                ]
            ],
            'default_font' => 'gayathri'
        ]);
        $mpdf->SetFont('dejavusanscondensed');
        $mpdf->simpleTables=true;
        // $mpdf->packTableData=true;
        // $mpdf->keep_table_proportions=TRUE;
        // $mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit=1;       
        // $users = User::all();
        // foreach($users as $user)
        // {
        //     $mpdf->WriteHTML('<p style="font-size:28px;">'. $user->name .'</p> ');
        // }
        // calculate two numbers
        $users = User::all();
        $view = View::make('pdf', compact('users'));
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($view);
        $mpdf->Output();  
    }
}
```

In the generated pdf there is no borders but cell divisions and other layouts are ok, how to include borders for the entire table.( including cells, colums etc)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the style tag. Try to use stylesheet instead:

```
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/style.css');
//CSS
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);//This is css/style only and no body/html/text

//BODY
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);//This is html content, without <head> information.
```

Check out this [documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Until now that I am dropping some lines here, there is still something wrong with MPDF when dealing with table borders.
When you style `<td>` and add border there, what you can see in the output is just `border left` and `border right`, and **no** `border top` and `border down`. For me, so as to bypass the problem, I styled both  and  to get all the borders working, that is top, bottom, right, and left. I just shared my solution in case someone would find it useful.

```
table td, table th, table tr {
border: 1px solid #c9c9c9 !important
}
```